# How can I Initialize a global 1D array of type char with a number?

Tags: c, pointers

Initialize a global 1D array "StudentData" of type char with your ID (5 digits).
Using pointers syntax is mandatory in this part.
Can you give me some tips about doing that?

I tried doing this,

```
char *StudentData;
void loadData(){
        StudentData=(char*)"60897";
}
```

Is it right or should I try doing something else?

Comment: `char *StudentData` is a pointer, not an array. "Using pointers syntax is mandatory in this part."  Well do you want an array or a pointer? You need to pick one. Should the data be read/write or read-only?

Comment: No cast needed. Other than that, remember that all literal strings in C are actually arrays of characters (including the null-terminator), and that while these arrays are not constant you're not allowed to modify their contents. Which is why it's recommended to use `const char *` for pointing to literal strings.

Comment: As for the array versus pointer thing, you also have to remember (or learn) that all arrays can *decay* to a pointer to its first element. And that for all arrays and pointers, array indexing will be done using pointer arithmetic (for any array or pointer `p` and index `i`, the expression `p[i]` is exactly equal to `*(p + i)`).

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Out of all of C, implicit pointer decay is the one design flaw in my views. It doesn't make development any worse, actually slightly easier but it makes it so much more harder to learn the language. It's not worth it.

Answer (score 0):

While you are indeed using an array (the string literal actually is one), it is an *anonymous* one – and your `studentData` is only a pointer to that one.

> a global 1D array "StudentData"

I would rather interpret this as you are intended to have a true array with that name, so that would look like:

```
char studentData[N];
```

where `N` is a constant expression representing an appropriate size for your array, at least 5 as you need to be able to store 5 digits – possibly 6 if your ID should be represented as a C-string (such one needs one additional character holding the mandatory null-terminator!), or you go with a power of two right away (8 minimally).

> Using pointers syntax is mandatory in this part.

So you'll need a pointer to that array:

```
char* ptr = studentData;
```

You could now just use the pointer to assign values to:

```
*ptr++ = '0'; // dereferences the pointer, assigns a value to (in this
              // case a character representing the digit zero) and
              // increments it afterwards to point to the next character

// repeat this for the next four digits!

*ptr++ = 0; // terminating null character (note: no single quotes)
// or:
*ptr = 0;
// it's up to you to decide if incrementing yet another time actually
// is meaningful (first variant) or unnecessary (second variant)...
```

If there are no further requirements given you might have this code directly in `main` function or as a little bonus place it in another function being called from `main` like:

```
void loadData(size_t size, char data[size])
{
    // ideally size check with appropriate error handling

    // assignment as above
}

// in main:
loadData(sizeof(studentData), studentData);
```

Note: For *function parameters* all of `char* data`, `char data[]` or `char[someArbitrarySize]` are equivalent, if any size is given, it is simply ignored – we still can add it for documentation purposes, in above signature: to tell that an array with a size of (at least) `size` is expected. Note, too, that if there are more than one dimensions given this only applies for the *outer most* dimension, though!

Answer (score 0):

You probably want something along the lines of:

```
#include <string.h>  //This header has strcpy()

#define ENOUGH_DIGITS   5 //This is so you can easily modify ID length in the future

char StudentData[ENOUGH_DIGITS+1];  //Global array 1 bigger than the longest string

void loadData(){
   //Ask the compiler to put a read-only string somewhere in the data memory
   const char *myID = "60897";  
   //Copy the read-only string into the global array
   strcpy(StudentData,myID);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> 1D array "StudentData"

No no no. `StudentData` is not an array, it's a pointer. Arrays are blocks of memory while pointers are addresses to memory, which may or may not be an array. An array sometimes becomes a pointer, that's called decay.

`"60897"` is already a `char *` compatible. You can directly assign it to `StudentData`. Like this:

```
StudentData = "60897";
```

If you want to use an array, do this:

```
#include <string.h>
char StudentData[WHATEVER_IS_ENOUGH_TO_HOLD_THE_DATA]; /* allocate array.
 make sure that the size of the array accounts for the null 
terminating character. */
void loadData(){
        strcpy(StudentData, "60897"); //you can't directly assign to an array.
}
```